# Boost linking using cmake

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am using linux and my CMakeList.txt file is

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/local/lib)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_program_options")
    find_package(Boost 1.55 COMPONENTS system program_options filesystem REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
    if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "boost not found")
    endif()
    add_executable(main main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries( main ${Boost_LABRARIES} )
```

and i am getting the following errors. I am working on it from two days and now i am sick of it . Can any body help me please.cmake_

Errors:

```
 main.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to     
`boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
 main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to                                       
 `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'

  main.cpp:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to  
  `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'

  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `Boost_LABRARIES` should be `Boost_LIBRARIES`. You should also remove the `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...` line, that's never needed to link to libraries when using CMake (and it's non-portable anyway.)